# How to display snippets from a set of articles as the new HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsdom

1. *I am trying to figure out how to iterate through the *news articles*,
   and present the headline and first sentence in a new HTML. Essentially how to create and display a *snippet* starting from the top? I am stuck on this.*

---

This a sample HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Main Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrappermain">
        <h1>Heading 1.1 Up</h1>
        <section id="headlines">
            <h2>Heading 2.1</h2>
        </section>
        <section id="news">
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <article class="newsarticle">
                <h4>Heading level 4 - article title </h4>
                <p>Article text here.</p> 
                <p> Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. </p>

            </article>

            <article class="newsarticle">
                <h4>Another Heading </h4>
                <p>Another article text.</p>
                <p> Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. </p>
            </article>

            <article class="newsarticle">
                <h4>Yet One More Article</h4>
                <p>More and more text here.</p>
                <p> Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample.Text sample.Text sample. Text sample.Text sample. </p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you asking, *specifically*?

Comment: I insert the image to preview. The image demonstrate how the page is suppose to be. For example I need to move in JS the <h3>, <p> from its original position, more specifically I need to manipulate and organise and make it equal to that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate the DOM and generate the "snippets" list you mention is fairly straightforward. The javascript below is run once the DOM has been populated and uses `querySelectorAll` to find all the relevant articles to use in the display - see comments in the js.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>JavaScript</title>

        <script>
            const createsnippets=function(e){
                /* the reference node near where we will generate menu */
                let headlines=document.getElementById('headlines');
                /* utiity to add new dom element */
                const create=function(t,v,p){
                    let n=document.createElement( t );
                        n.innerHTML=v;
                    p.appendChild( n );
                    return n;
                };
                /* create the list */
                let ul=create( 'ul', null, document.body );

                /* find all articles and add new snippet headline */
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'article.newsarticle > h4' ) ).forEach( function( h4 ){
                    create( 'li', h4.textContent+' ... '+h4.nextElementSibling.innerText, ul );
                });

                /* refactor HTMl to ensure layout is "just so" */
                headlines.parentNode.insertBefore( ul, headlines.nextSibling )
            }

            /* when the DOM is ready, create the list of headline snippets */
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', createsnippets );
        </script>

        <style>
            ul{ color:red; }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrappermain'>
            <h1>Bizzare News Mash Up</h1>
            <section id='headlines'>
                <h2>Bizzare News Summary</h2>
            </section>
            <section id='news'>
                <h3>News Stories in Full</h3>
                <article class='newsarticle'>
                    <h4>What a load of Bull!</h4>
                    <p>Chinese Kung Fu Masters are seeking the ultimate opponents</p>
                    <p>Several times a week, kung fu teacher Ren Ruzhi enters a ring to spar with a bovine opponent around
                        five times his weight and capable of killing him.</p>
                    <p>Ren’s mixing of martial arts and bullfighting worries his mother, but the 24-year-old has never been
                        hurt. Besides, he says, grappling with a snorting bull is exciting.</p>
                    <p>It symbolizes the bravery of a man,” Ren told Reuters in Jiaxing in China’s eastern province of
                        Zhejiang.</P>
                    <p>Unlike Spain’s more famous sport, the Chinese variant of
                        bullfighting involves no swords or gore but instead fuses the moves of wrestling with the skill and
                        speed of kung fu to bring down beasts weighing up to 400 kg (882 lb).</p>
                    <p>“Spanish bullfighting is more like a performance or a show,” said Hua Yang, a 41-year-old enthusiast
                        who watched a bullfight during a visit to Spain.</p>
                </article>
                <article class='newsarticle'>
                    <h4>Has Anybody got a Tissue?</h4>
                    <p>A Hawaiian monk seal got an eel caught in its nose ― and it wasn’t the first time for these
                        endangered creatures.</p>
                    <p>The Hawaiian Monk Seal Research Program posted a startling pic of the poor pup on Monday, and the
                        National Oceanic
                        and Atmospheric Administration Fisheries provided more details in a post on Wednesday.</p>
                    <p>The administration said it has seen the same “eels in noses” phenomenon nearly a handful of times in
                        the last few years.</p>
                    <p>“We don’t know if this is just some strange statistical anomaly or something we will see more of in
                        the future,”
                        the NOAA wrote.</p>
                    <p>The agency has two theories on why it happened in this case: A cornered eel was trying to defend
                        itself or escape, and
                        wound up in the seal’s nose. Or the seal could have swallowed the eel first and regurgitated its
                        prey out the wrong way.</p>
                </article>
                <article class='newsarticle'>
                    <h4>Dog Pulls Off Spectacular Save During Argentina Soccer Match</h4>
                    <p>A pooch invaded the pitch during a Federal A league match between Juventud Unida and Defensores de
                        Belgrano over the weekend.</p>
                    <p>Juventud Unida were already comfortably ahead against Defensores de Belgrano in their league clash
                        when the dog
                        made his unexpected cameo.</p>
                    <p>Belgrano looked on course to go four goals down when their goalkeeper kicked the ball against a
                        Juventud player,
                        who then took a shot towards the empty net.</p>
                    <p>But in the nick of time, a dog came out of nowhere to race across the line and nod the ball away from
                        goal.</p>
                    <p>Unfortunately, the dog was unable to inspire a comeback as Juventud went on to win the match 3-0.</p>
                </article>
                <article class='newsarticle'>
                    <h4>Nobody Beats The Laws of Nature</h4>
                    <p>A 69-year-old Dutch man has failed in his attempt to legally declare himself 20 years younger.</p>
                    <p>Last month, motivational speaker Emile Ratelband filed a lawsuit against the Dutch government
                        requesting that his
                        date of birth be switched from March 11, 1949, to March 11, 1969.</p>
                    <p>n Monday, a court in the Netherlands city of Arnhem rejected his age-changing application, saying
                        that while Ratelband
                        “is at liberty to feel 20 years younger than his real age and to act accordingly,” actually changing
                        the birth certificate
                        is not possible.</p>
                </article>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try those links for example:

[Xah Lee](http://xahlee.info/js/dom_common_dom_methods.html)

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Basically you need to assign DOM elements to variables, for example:

```
//multiple elements
var articles = document.querySelectorAll('. newsarticle');

//one element
var article = document.getElementById('news');
```

The *articles* variable will act similar to an array, so you can loop through it. Each element can have a parent, siblings, etc. There are various methods of accessing them and modifying.

That's just to get you going. Guys here don't like when someone asks others to do the work for him/her. Internet is full of documentations, good luck :)